# Tableau - Filter on maximum date within dimension

Tags: tableau-api

I have data that are structured as so:

```
| Node | Update Datetime | Measure Values |  
|------|-----------------|----------------|
| A    |  2018-01-01     |  1             |
| A    |  2018-01-05     |  3             |
| A    |  2018-01-06     |  4             |
| B    |  2018-01-02     |  2             |
| B    |  2018-01-03     |  4             |
```

The `nodes`are updated over time with the `measure values` showing the node's value at the time of data entry, meaning just filtering on a date range will overstate the node's value. The report needs to be responsive or else I would just do this in sql, but as it stands I need to be able to keep only the rows that contain the maximum `datetime` value within each node, after the entire dataset is filtered on a general date window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think creating a level-of-detail (LOD) calculated field and using it as a filter is the cleanest and quickest way to achieve the desired filter.

See Option 2 here -- http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/setting-default-date-to-most-recent-date-on-a-quick-filter?lang=en

Let me know if that does not work.

(FYI Tableau Community Forums is another resource for Tableau questions. I use both sites)

Comment: The second method did work, after a fashion. The instructions specify `[Order Date] = {FIXED : MAX([Order Date])}` but I had to use `[Node] = {FIXED : MAX([Update Datetime])}` to get things to work in my application. Unfortunately this still doesn't work for my application and I ended up doing some more SQL to add a `endWindow` column that allows me to filter the records based on a date parameter.

Comment: Interesting, the first calculation seems more intuitive to me as well. Happy to hear you got it working though you ultimately took it a different direction.